# Iterating through a column in a CSV file in C

Tags: c, loops, csv

Not sure how to get loop through the columns only

Given the function header 
        `double getMin(char csvfile[], char column[]);` 
return the minimum score of the specified column.

When implementing the above functions, you can assume csvfile is a valid CSV file and it can always be opened for reading, and the column parameter is a short form of the column heading and it starts with a letter (P for Participation, C for Challenge, and L for Lab) followed by a chapter number, a dot, and a section number. For example,  P5.6, C5.4 and L5.25 represent the column headings 5.6 – Participation, 5.4 – Challenge, and 5.25 – Lab respectively. You shall return -2.0 (double) or 2 (integer) if the corresponding column name or student name does not exist, and -1.0 or 1 if the corresponding column is optional.

Ex. file-

Last name,First name,5.1 - Participation (11),5.2 - Participation (20), 5.1 - Challenge (0),5.2 - Challenge (9), 5.25 - Lab (10)
Alvarez,Abel,100,100,100,100,100
Mendez,Charlene,0,0,0,0,0
Zimmerman,Drew,100,100,100,100,60

Comment: `column[]` is wrong. It's missing its type, it's not a value; it's an array (a pointer to be exact).

Comment: "Can someone please explain how to loop through that column?" It seems to be an homework. Didn't your teacher give you more directives?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to fix errors or add information. Please show an example how the CSV file looks like, how the function will be called and what output you expect for the given example input. (with explanation if necessary)

Comment: What code have you tried so far? I'm not sure how looping through the contents of `column` is going to get you anything remotely like what you've been asked for tho

Comment: The professor said to use fgets(...) and strsep(...) and thats all the advice she gave us. What other method(s) would be quicker than looping through the column?

Answer (score 0):

1. set accumulator to 0.
2. set numberoflines to 0.
3. read the file line by line (but ignore first header line); goto 6 if no more lines
4. for each line skip `n-1` commas (beware commas embedded in quotes) increment numberoflines and add the value to the accumulator
5. goto 3.
6. divide accumulator by numberoflines and return.